# Finding the next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<button class="volumen-btn" onclick="niceFunction()>
<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</button>
<div class="volume-control-container" id="container1" style="display:none;">
<input type="range" name="blabla" class="volume-range" id="range1">
</div>
<div class="randomdiv">
</div>

<!-- New Volume Button -->

<button class="volumen-btn" onclick="niceFunction()>
<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</button>
<div class="volume-control-container" id="container1" style="display:none;">
<input type="range" name="blabla" class="volume-range" id="range1">
</div>
```

JS Function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".volume-btn").click(function() {
        volumeControl();
    });
});


function volumeControl(){
   $(this).siblings('.volume-control-container').toggle()
}
```

With JS I want to click on `volume-btn` and then find the closest `volume-control-container` and toggle its display. I have checked out similar/duplicate questions, but just couldn't get it to work to my specific question.

JsFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/eltonfrederik/4Pa4g/1

Comment: I just added my JS attempt

Comment: Can you also post your event listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.siblings('.volume-control-container')`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to find the closest `.volume-control-container`.

I think this is a bit of a better solution, as it is markup agnostic. Meaning that if you move around your controls, this will still give you the `.volume-control-container` you want (so long as it is still a sibling of your button).

**Update**

Put your `volumeControl()` function inside your `$(document).ready()` or before it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the closest next element like this. From your code this will give you the div that has the volume-control-container class.

```
$( ".volumen-btn" ).next();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".volumen-btn").next().toggle();
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQUK7/) example

Comment: Hey can you help me debug why this solution didnt work for me, in chat?